# Should I use an external power supply for controlling 4 servos?

Tags: gpio, power-supply, servo

So I have for servos that I could connect to a breadboard and to raspberry pi GPIO 5V pin to power them. But I have read that That is not safe it can damage the pi. Is that true?

instead of using raspberry pi as power supply I should use an external power supply instead.

I have tried connecting 2 servos to the 2 5V pins and that worked fined. But I'm worried that using the 5v pin is bad in the long term.

And since Im gonna have at least 4 servos im worried that connecting them to a breadboard and the 5V pin is bad and will damage the pi

Comment: absolutely yes and yes

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will use exteranal power supply

Answer (score 3):

If you power the Pi via its microUSB socket you will only be able to supply a limited amount of current to the Pi and its peripherals (screen, USB, servos etc).

You need to calculate how much spare current is available for powering servos and see if there is enough.

We can't do that for you.  We don't know the current draw of the servos you plan to use.

In your situation I would assume you need an external power supply and plan accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. I will use external power